# Is there any native library to check the validity of SSL certificates in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl

I was using this code to check the validity of SSL certificates

```
var request = require('request');

var options_error = {
    url: post_url,
    method: 'GET',
    auth: {
      user: username,
      password: password
    }
}

request(options_error, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})
```

Even though the certificate is valid on the site, I still got this error

```
{ Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

I have already searched about this error on here. However, I have no idea how to fix it since the certificate is already valid. I am just wondering if there is any other libraries in Nodejs to check it, without using request library. Any helps

Comment: What do you exactly want to do and is there any limitation to use well-known http client `npm` packages in your project?

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand Before the SSL certificate is invalid, it gave the same error. Then i went to update the certificate, and it is valid now. When I run the code, it still gave me this error. I only tried request library.

Comment: `https` is the standard library and you need nothing to install but it is not easy to use it. I would sugggest [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) which is used by many other libraries as `http client`.